# grep for pods and select each result and pass a command in loop

Tags: shell, kubernetes, awk, grep

I have few pods running in my kubernetes cluster. I am developing a shell script and I want to grep for few pods and want to select each pod from the grep result to execute a command.
Lets say I grep few pods by command :

```
kubectl get pods | grep test
```

the results are:

```
Test-0

Test-1 

Test-2
```

From the result, I want to select each pod and execute a command for it in a loop.

for example:

for first pod:

```
kubectl exec -it Test-0 -- mysqldump.......
```

after finishing the first pod, it has to process the second pod and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get pods name and then use "for" to execute command in each pod

```
#!/bin/bash

pods=$(kubectl get pods | awk '{print $2}' | grep -i test)

for i in $pods
do
  kubectl exec -it $i -- echo "test"
done
```

Comment: Glad this helped the OP, but a general note for future readers. You can do `awk '/test/{print $2}'` to save an unnecessary pipe; there is no need for `grep` and `awk` in most cases.  also, as the other answers mentioned, `-oname` would also remove the need to do `awk` or `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for pod in $(kubectl get pod -oname |grep -i Test ); do
  kubectl exec "$pod" -- ls -ltr ;
done
```

Replace `ls -ltr` with `mysqldump .....`

Answer (score 0):

Select your target pods using labels is less error prone and can do multiple matching:

```
kubectl get pods --selector <key>=<value>,<key>=<value> --namespace <name> -oname | xargs -I{} kubectl exec -it {} --namespace <name> -- mysqldump ...
```